# Make mouse pointer size bigger, when using 2x scaling over XRDP

Tags: xfce, xrdp, rdp, x11rdp

I have set up XRDP with XFCE on Ubuntu Server 22.04. Since the Window PC is using a 4K monitor, when I connected to Ubuntu from the Windows PC using RDP (full screen), the resolution became 4K and everything was small. I set Settings -> Appearance-> Settings -> Window Scaling to "2x" and re-logged in. Everything seems to be in the correct size but the mouse pointer size remains the same, and is too small. I have tried changing Settings -> Mouse and Touchpad -> Theme -> Cursor Size, but it had no effect. Is there a way to make the mouse pointer bigger over XRDP?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same issue today. Downloaded a different mouse theme from
https://www.xfce-look.org/browse?cat=107 and the size of the cursor can be modified as normal. There's still a slight issue though. The cursor will get cut-offed when the size exceeds a certain limit.